# How to call a function on .change()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Summary**: I would like to call an external function upon a status change for a checkbox.

The following code which includes the function to call upon the change **works** (code available at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/ybg48u0j/), commented section)

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">
```

JS

```
$("#cb").change(function () {
        if ($("#cb").prop('checked'))
        {
            alert('checked');
        } else {
            alert('unchecked')
        }
    });
```

As expected, an `alert` is raised when checking or unchecking the checkbox.

---

I now want to [move the `function` part outside the `.change()` method](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/ybg48u0j/):

```
$("#cb").change(alertme());

function alertme () {
        if ($("#cb").prop('checked'))
        {
            alert('checked');
        } else {
            alert('unchecked')
        }
    }
```

**This does not work anymore (no alert on status change). Why is it so?**

Comment: `alertme` instead of `alertme()`

Comment: The answers are clear, thanks. The downvotes, well, ...

Comment: You have two ways:

first:

    `$("#cb").change(alertme);`


Second:

    `$("#cb").change(function() {
        alertme();
    });`
    

I prefer second version, you need to pass reference of function as you can see or reproduce a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to just pass the function name to the change event, not actually call the function and pass the return value. Use this instead:

```
$("#cb").change(alertme);
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need the function definition, don't execute it:

```
$("#cb").change(alertme);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't execute the function, just pass it as a callback:

```
$("#cb").change(alertme);

function alertme () {
        if ($("#cb").prop('checked'))
        {
            alert('checked');
        } else {
            alert('unchecked')
        }
    }
```